# Is it possible to configure Azure Data Factory to run custom activity in a container-enabled pools in Azure Batch?

Tags: azure, containers, azure-data-factory, azure-batch

I'm building a data pipeline with custom activities and I would like to run them in containers, in a specially prepared images. My first attempt to configure pipeline failed with :

> Container-enabled compute node requires task container settings.

```
{
    "exitcode": null,
    "errorCategory": 0,
    "code": "ContainerTaskSettingsNotFound",
    "message": "Container-enabled compute node requires task container settings",
    "details": null,
    "computeInformation": "{\"account\":\"stanswenergydatafactory\",\"poolName\":\"dotnet\",\"vmSize\":\"standard_a1\"}",
    "effectiveIntegrationRuntime": "DefaultIntegrationRuntime (West US 2)",
    "executionDuration": 17432
}
```

Is it possible to configure Azure Data Factory to pass necessary settings to Azure Batch?

Comment: I got reply from ADF product team saying that it is not currently possible.

Comment: If you want Microsoft to develop this feature, please upvote on this voice-of-customer thread: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/35803975-run-containers-through-data-factory-custom-activit